# Does setting the same element in a list does something at all?

Tags: java

I have a code similar to this:

```
public class PlayerRound {
    private final List<Strip> playerStrips = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addStrip(final Strip aStrip) {
        // ...
        if (playerStrips.contains(aStrip)) {
            playerStrips.set(playerStrips.indexOf(aStrip), aStrip); // DOES THIS LINE CHANGE SOMETHING?
        }
        // ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(
        appliesTo = "Strip",
        indexes = {
            @Index(name = "IDX_RoundStrip", columnNames = {"round_id"}),
            @Index(name = "IDX_UserStrip", columnNames = {"user_id"})
        }
)
public class Strip implements Serializable, IAnnotatedProxy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Transient
    private Integer tempId = tempIdx++;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Boolean areEqual = Boolean.FALSE;
        if (obj != null && getClass() == obj.getClass()) {
            final Strip other = (Strip) obj;
            if (null == this.id && null == other.id) {
                if (this.tempId.equals(other.tempId)) {
                    areEqual = Boolean.TRUE;
                }
            } else if (null != this.id) {
                if (this.id.equals(other.id)
                        || this.id.equals(other.tempId)) {
                    areEqual = Boolean.TRUE;
                }
            } else if (null != other.id) {
                if (other.id.equals(this.id)
                        || other.id.equals(this.tempId)) {
                    areEqual = Boolean.TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        return areEqual;
    }
}
```

My question is: can I safely delete the line that sets the element that already is on the list on the same position?

Does this line does something that I don't know?

Comment: It'll throw an exception if doesn't contain `aStrip` which might interrupt your program flow

Comment: Furthermore: if it does contain an object with an equal value there will now be a reference from the variable `aStrip` inside `addStrip` connected to that entry inside the collection. This means that further changes to `aStrip` inside `addStrip` will be reflected inside the collection since they now have both value *and* referential equality.

Comment: Sorry @JeroenVannevel I think you saw the old version. I added a condition to check if `aStrip` is already in the list. This way it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that code is totally useless. **Unless....**

---

#### Same element twice

As it is a List, what happens if it contains the element twice?

Let's say we have a List containing two elements of the type `Strip`:

```
stripA, stripB
```

stripA and stripB are **equal**, that is, the class have implemented `.equals`. Then and only then, this code will do something useful. If `aStrip` is `stripB` then it will modify the list to become:

```
stripB, stripB
```

#### One inside, one outside, both `.equals`

The same is true if the List contains `stripA` only and you call the method with `aStrip` again as `stripB`. Remember that `stripA.equals(stripB)` is true so here's what happens:

```
 if (playerStrips.contains(aStrip)) {
```

Yes. `.contains` on a `Collection` uses `.equals` to see if it contains or not, so this will return true.

```
 playerStrips.indexOf(aStrip)
```

indexOf also uses `.equals` and the index of `stripA` is returned.

```
playerStrips.set(playerStrips.indexOf(aStrip), aStrip);
```

So what happens here is that the index of `stripA` is set to `stripB`.

**Small Improvement**

There's really no reason to use both `indexOf` **and** `contains`. You could do this instead:

```
int index = playerStrips.indexOf(aStrip);
if (index != -1) {
    playerStrips.set(index, aStrip);
}
```

**However**

If this functionality has been added because of this reason, I personally think it is a **bad reason** to add it. **This code is more confusing than anything else.** Do it differently. Either `aStrip` should not really be equal to `bStrip`, or something else should be modified. The reason for why one would want to replace `aStrip` with `bStrip` when they are already `equal` goes beyond my understanding.

---

## Strip.equals

Holy.... mess!

First of, why use `Boolean` when you can use `boolean`? Secondly, why use a `boolean` at all when you can use `return`?

Also, you could probably use `instanceof` instead of `getClass`. But you should [look at the StackOverflow question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals).

I have to question the usage of `tempID`, it does not feel like a clean solution to me - whatever problem it is meant to solve.

By following the program execution, you can see that if one of those `if (condition) return true` is not true that the only possible return value is false. Therefore, it can be simplified with `return condition;`

Because of the above, there will be no reason to use any `else` as there's a `return` inside the previous `if`.

Therefore, your `.equals` method can be simplified to:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Strip) {
        final Strip other = (Strip) obj;
        if (null == this.id && null == other.id) {
            return this.tempId.equals(other.tempId);
        }
        if (null != this.id) {
            return this.id.equals(other.id)
                    || this.id.equals(other.tempId);
        }
        if (null != other.id) {
            return other.id.equals(this.id)
                    || other.id.equals(this.tempId);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You could have two instances of `Strip` which are equal to each other but `equals()` does not use all of the fields. For example, `aStrip.userId` might not the same as `bStrip.userId` although `aStrip.equals(bStrip)` is `true`.

Comment: @palacsint Absolutely, I think I've made that clear that it depends on the `.equals` implementation, and now that the actual implementation has been posted also, I've written a review of it.

Comment: You can replace the last `if (null != other.id) { ... }` with simply `return other.id.equals(this.tempId)`. I would also remove all the `this.` from that method.

Comment: Thanks for the review @SimonAndréForsberg. I have to deal with this messy code on this project. I will try to improve it day by day.

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto Well, if it's any comfort, I know the feeling of dealing with messy code!